# Why is no username and email show in up on the list when I already ran the git config --global user....(I am sure that name and email are correct)

Tags: git, github

Why is no username and email show in up on the list when I already ran the git config --global user....(I am sure that name and email are correct)

which step is mistake?

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read.

Comment: `git config --global user.name"foo"` asks for the value of a configuration option named `user.namefoo`; it does not set the option `user.name` to the value `foo`. You are just missing a space to provide the correct number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space missing between the config key and your name/email.

Answer (score 0):

ya you miss the space.
you must write with space at this.

git config --global user.email "Youremail@com"

git config --global user.email "YourName"

cmiiw